# C# -SQLCommand -Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: 69470570' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql

I'm new with programing and need some help here.

Search all over the internet and couldn't find solution.

I have small code, using WinForms application with c#

This is the part of the problematic part:

```
myConnection.Open();

sqlCommand myCommand16 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Units]  where unitid='" + textBox1.Text + "'", myConnection);
            internalUnitId = myCommand16.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            
SqlCommand myCommand15 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 REQUESTID FROM [dbo].[ActivationProcStatusMsgd]  where unitsid='" + internalUnitId + "'  order by id desc", myConnection);
label11.Text = myCommand15.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
// till here all ok.


            


SqlCommand myCommand25 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1  [OriginalReqId]  FROM [dbo].[ActivationRequestsHistory]  where unitsid='" + internalUnitId + "' and originalreqid='" + label11 + "'  order by id desc", myConnection);
label18.Text = myCommand25.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
//in This part above i'm getting the exception
```

In the example below i'm replacing the "label11" with 69470570, and everything is ok.dont understand the different

```
   //  SqlCommand myCommand25 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1  [OriginalReqId]  FROM [dbo].[ActivationRequestsHistory]  where unitsid='" + internalUnitId + "' and originalreqid='69470570'  order by id desc", myConnection);
            label18.Text = myCommand25.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Thanks in advance
Ohad

Comment: Sorry, don't quite understand your quest, but here's a few recommendations for you: 1. try to name the controls better don't use label1, label2 2. try to use Parameterized SQL http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in below line :

```
SqlCommand myCommand25 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1  [OriginalReqId]  FROM [dbo].[ActivationRequestsHistory]  where unitsid='" + internalUnitId + "' and originalreqid='" + label11 + "'  order by id desc", myConnection);
```

here you have query formation like :

```
originalreqid='" + label11 + "'
```

It should be :

```
originalreqid='" + label11.Text + "'
```

Complete line will be :

```
SqlCommand myCommand25 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1  [OriginalReqId]  FROM [dbo].[ActivationRequestsHistory]  where unitsid='" + internalUnitId + "' and originalreqid='" + label11.Text + "'  order by id desc", myConnection);
```

Cause :

`label11`  is just a object which you are using. You will have to mention its property `.Text` so as to get proper value.

Comment: Wow.. That was fast :). just tried and it works! -Thanks a lot to all guys .Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of label11 in query write label11.Text

Answer (score 0):

you missed to add .Text near Label11 :

```
SqlCommand myCommand25 = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1  [OriginalReqId]  FROM [dbo].[ActivationRequestsHistory]  where unitsid='" + internalUnitId + "' and originalreqid='" + label11.Text + "'  order by id desc", myConnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use label11.Text. label11 is name id of the label. It is just an object and cannot be converted to int.